# Laravel 4 form submit in new window/tab

Tags: forms, laravel

I have a form with to submit buttons (preview/save). 
One is for preview the form data (without saving it to DB), the other is to save the data to DB if the preview looks fine.
Is there a way to open the preview in a new tab or window.
I have tried it with

```
{{ Form::submit('preview', ['name' => 'preview', 'target' => '_blank']) }}
```

This deosn't work. 
I also tried it with some JS (onlick...), but no luck.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a modal, with very basic javascript to populate the modal from input values

Comment: If you want to submit a form an open the action URL in a new window/tab you need to add the `target="_blank"` attribute on the `<form>` tag, not the submit button. So using the form builder you should have something this: `{!! Form::open(['url' => '/form/action/url/goes/here', 'target' => '_blank']) !!}`.

Answer (score 0):

type target="_blank" next to form action or method